# sql distinct top 6 random

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have 3 tables:

- Network: NetworkId
- Networkmembers: network_id, user_id
- Users: userId

What I want is to show 6 random network where the user is not already a member.

I have tried this, but it is not working:

```vb
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT TOP 6 * FROM network, networkmembers WHERE networkId = network_id AND user_id <> " & Request.Cookies("userId") & " AND isPublic = True ORDER BY rnd(networkId)"
```

Comment: What's not working? Error, not providing any results, providing wrong results, etc.? What is the definition of a member?

Comment: I get this error: ORDER BY clause (rnd(networkId)) conflicts with DISTINCT

Comment: your column ispublic belongs to no table?

Comment: it belongs to the table network

Answer (score 0):

First create an unsorted recordset with distinct records, then select Top 6 from this:

```vb
sql = _
    "SELECT TOP 6 * " & _
    "FROM " & _
    "    (SELECT Distinct * " & _
    "    FROM Network " & _
    "    INNER JOIN networkmembers ON networkId = network_id " & _
    "    WHERE user_id <> " & Request.Cookies("userId") & " AND isPublic = True) AS T " & _
    "ORDER BY Rnd(-Timer() * [ID])"
```

where `ID` is the unique key of the recordset.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using an access database and get an error: Join expression not supported.

Comment: Then there is a mismatch between the fields you join on. Double-check the data types and field types.